# How to convert a number into a string without type conversion?

Tags: python, string, while-loop, integer, data-conversion

The below code gives the required result for the numbers, not including 0, I am looking for a solution where I can include those numbers as well.

```
number = int(input('enter the number'))

digits = '0123456789'
result = ''
while number != 0:
  result = digits[number % 10] + result
  number = number//10

print(result)
```

Comment: `if result == '': result = '0'` ... ?

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to Achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that your program outputs an empty string instead of '0', and that you want to fix that, you can just add this to your program:

```py
if result == "":
    result = "0"
```

If the input is 0, the condition in the while loop is immediately false, and so it never runs.

Comment: If the user enters 1234, it will give the output '1234'. But if the user enters 0000, it is not giving '0000' because the while loop will break on the first instance only.

Comment: @DivyajitDJ, as far as I know, there is no way around this, because `int("0000")` would give you `0`.